# LoadGrammar for speech recognization

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

```
sre.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set recording souce to default

RecognitionResult Result = sre.Recognize(); // record sound and recognize
string ResultString = "";
// add all recognized words to the result string
foreach (RecognizedWordUnit w in Result.Words)
{
     ResultString += w.Text;
}
```

How to detect any words we speak instead of assign words list to LoadGrammar ?

I want to detect perfect word what i speak 
right now it detects any random words.

Comment: Just some short information (not an answer), I'm not native English speaker and the Speach recognizer missunderstood words and complete sentences when I spoke for an application I made. Ended up with a dictonary of words in the end for me so that it could match/understand correclty.

Answer (score 0):

Almost like in a normal conversation it's really hard to recognize separate words. ASR systems including the one you use benefit from having some context information. The most you can do is to make a grammar including all words you'd like to be recognized, but the quality of recognition will drop correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to train the recognizer, as it doesn't do well with non-native speakers by default.   There's an API that allows you to specify custom text, but an easy way to do this is to go to `Control Panel\Ease of Access\Speech Recognition` and click on 'Train your computer to better understand you'.